# Number of Connected Components in an Open Set from which a Point is Removed

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I don't see the reasoning clearly behind the number of connected components in the following example taken from *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu (First Edition, page no. 48).

[image]

My points of confusion are as follows.

1. In the *Solution* above I don't see why $U-\lbrace p \rbrace$ has four connected components.
2. The *Solution* doesn't mention the number of connected components of $B - \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ for $n \geq 2$. How can I determine it so that I can use the fact that the number of connected components is a topological property; i.e., preserved under homeomorphism to complete the solution?
3. In the first line of the *Solution*, we have assumed that $p \in U \cong B(0, \epsilon)$. Is that an assumption that the homeomorphism maps $p \in U$ to $0 \in B(0, \epsilon)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your third question is *yes*; the first sentence of the solution says explicitly that $p$ has a nbhd $U$ homeomorphic to an open ball $B(0,\epsilon)$ **with** $p$ **mapping to** $0$. Clearly the mapping referred to must be the homeomorphism taking $U$ to $B(0,\epsilon)$.

As for the first question, take $p$ to be the point where the arms of the cross come together: when you remove that point, the deleted cross that remains is the disjoint union of the four arms, each of which is homeomorphic either to $(0,1]$, if they include their far endpoints, or to $(0,1)$, if they do not. Each is therefore a connected set, and each is relatively open in the deleted cross, so they its connected components. Any open nbhd of $p$ must intersect each of them, so it must have at least four connected components. (It actually could have more, depending on the precise open set $U$.)

I don’t understand your second question, because the solution tells you exactly how many components an ball in $\Bbb R^n$ has after its centre point is deleted: it has one connected component (‘is ... connected’) if $n\ge 2$ and has two connected components if $n=1$.